# Compare 2 images with minimum difference value

Tags: command-line

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question, I'll update/move my question if it is.

There is a linux command `compare` that I'm using to compare a difference between 2 images, this is the command:

`compare 1.jpg 2.jpg diff.jpg`

It's working very well, the problem is: if both images has no difference, it still creates a diff file, and you open this file and it's just a blank image.

Is there a way to tell this command to just create this diff file only if there is actually a difference between these 2 images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the [ImageMagick compare command](https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php), there doesn't seem to be an option to do that; however the command's exit status provides a way to kludge it by conditionally deleting the output file afterwards:

> ```
>    The compare program returns 2 on error otherwise 0 if  the  images  are
>    similar or 1 if they are dissimilar.
> ```

i.e. the command "succeeds" only if the files are not dissimilar. So you could write a simple shell function wrapper and (optionally alias it):

```
mycompare () 
{ 
    command compare "$@" && rm -- "${!#}"
}

alias compare='mycompare'
```

The `${!#}` is a bash indirect reference that expands to the last positional parameter (which in this case will be the name of the output file).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll need to study a bit what you said and try to implement :-)